# rails jbuilder getting Called id for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jbuilder

I'm trying to use jbuilder gem to format json output.

Controller

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
def tree
  @locations = Location.all
end
```

tree.json.jbuilder

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.id @location.id
  json.name @location.name
end
```

Test using url:

```
http://localhost:5000/locations/tree.json
```

Results:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: Jbuilder.encode do |json|
2:   json.id @location.id
3:   json.name @location.name
4: end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't seem to define `@location` in the code you have posted.
you should iterate over your locations, *jbuilder* lets you do it for example like this:

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.locations @locations do |location|
    json.id location.id
    json.name location.name
  end
end
```

see the [docs](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder#readme) if you want a flat array instead.